# twisted and ulimit

Tags: twisted, ulimit

I run command in bash:

```
ulimit
my_command
```

How to use ulimit ( or analog function ) in twisted ?

```
from twisted.internet import protocol, utils, reactor


def r():
    utils.getProcessOutputAndValue('my_command')

reactor.callWhenRunning(r)
reactor.run()
```

Answer (score 1):

The [resource](http://docs.python.org/library/resource.html) stdlib module.